# How can I get iOS to cache HTML5 documents with query parameters?

Tags: ios, html, mobile-safari, manifest

I am attempting to open mobile safari from an iOS app to open an offline HTML5 app with openURL:

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8080/blargh.html"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

blargh.html has an HTML5 manifest:

That manifest contains the html file:
CACHE MANIFEST
blargh.html

This all works as expected, when I open the URL from my iOS app, it is cached properly and works offline.  However, it *doesn't* cache properly if I include dynamic cgi params:

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:8080/blargh.html?q=p"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];

This basically means that I can't open an offline HTML5 app from an iOS app and pass it params and have it cache properly.  I need to open the app in mobile safari and not a webview for reasons that are beyond this post.  As far as I am aware there is no way to send post params through openURL.  I would have hoped that mobile safari's caching system would have been smart enough to ignore cgi params.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Query params muck up the app cache because it's intended for static content.  The usual approach is to load a static page and then use JavaScript to populate it dynamically, caching any data in [DOM Storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) so that you can use it offline too.

However, if you just need to cache the one file and your server supports routing or [URL re-writing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine), then you can take advantage of the fact that the page that contains the link to the `appcache` file is always cached, so doesn't itself have to be listed in the manifest.

Re-write your URL from this:

```
http://localhost:8080/blargh.html?q=p
```

To:

```
http://localhost:8080/blargh.html/q/p
```

Comment: In ios I can only open mobile safari with a URL, and I need to pass the parameters to mobile safari through that URL (I don't see any other way to make mobile safari aware of these parameters).  But I am confused about how the rewriting on the server-side helps. I am trying to get the browser to completely handle the request on the client side without requesting anything from the server (after the first load of course.  So, if I request http://localhost:8080/blargh.html/q/p on the client side is the implication that the appcache will happily serve that from http://localhost:8080/blargh.html?

Comment: @MarkCorner No, it'll happily serve that from `http://localhost:8080/blarg.html/q/p` - that's the point, it's taking the parameters and making them look like a file.  That's what I meant by 'if you just need to cache the one file'.  If it's confusing why that might help, maybe you can be more clear in your question about what you want?  Is the same user going to need the same page but with different parameters?

Comment: Yes, sorry that wasn't clear, the same user will need the same page with different parameters so it seems like that solution wouldn't work....  Perhaps there is some other iOS trick I am missing.

Comment: @MarkCorner I don't think so, if there's dynamic data involved use DOM Storage as I mentioned first.  Use a fragment identifier instead of a query, read the variables from the [`location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) with JavaScript.